# Setting default JDK version for Android Studio Windows

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have searched and could not find a solution for this problem.

```
Error:Buildtools 24.0.2 requires Java 1.8 or above.  Current JDK version is 1.7.
```

My JAVA_HOME variable in path variable is pointing to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101

I don't know what I am missing and I couldn't find any settings in Android Studio to change the JDK path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have proper location and version of JDK

Go to `File -> Project Structure`. You would see this window:

[image]

You can also add `compileOptions` in your `app/build.gradle` file:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Comment: I am using android studio 2.1.3 and i am not able to see any project setting inside file!. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: sorry my mistake. Open `File -> Project Structure` then you would see the window like above